# Can't get suggestions in snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have customized one snippet:

```
"Import for eslint": {
        "prefix": "import",
        "body": [
            "import { $2 } from '$1'",
        ],
        "description": "import (eslint)"
    }
```

Though it works well, but I can't get suggestions when you code the file path(`$1`), Like this:
[the image No Suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAGRZ.png)
the code has highlight background, and don't have suggestions, How should I do some work to implement the feature like this:
[only has cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6r5K.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to

```
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
```

`true` is the default which may be preventing you from seeing suggestions inside your snippet.  You want `false`.